# print div html code with css

Tags: html, css

I have this html code

```js
function printDiv(divName) {
  var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
  var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

  document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

  window.print();

  document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s6 l6">
      <div class="center" id="div_id" style="height: 400px;width: 600px; position:relative; background-color: #ff0;">
        <img class="responsive-img" id="profile" width="200" src="https://picsum.photos/200">
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col s6 l6">
      <div class="card-panel" id="first_name">
        <span class="black-text"></span>
      </div>
      <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" id="print" onclick="printDiv('div_id')">PRINT</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

what I want is to print the div tag that contains the image with the css format or at least the position. is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javascript is printing the `innerHTML` of the `div` (the `img` only). By changing the `printContents` variable to `outerHTML` you also get the `div` with its styling:

```
var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).outerHTML;
```

```js
function printDiv(divName) {
  var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).outerHTML;
  var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

  document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

  window.print();

  document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```

```css
body { -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s6 l6">
      <div class="center" id="div_id" style="height: 400px;width: 600px; position:relative; background-color: #ff0;">
        <img class="responsive-img" id="profile" width="200" src="https://picsum.photos/200">
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col s6 l6">
      <div class="card-panel" id="first_name">
        <span class="black-text"></span>
      </div>
      <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" id="print" onclick="printDiv('div_id')">PRINT</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the snippet doesnt include the yellow bg of the div

Comment: Browser ignore background color by default. Adding the CSS `body { -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important; }` enables it for Chrome.

Comment: @ChanMT I never knew of this property. I've added it to the answer.

Comment: how do I include positioning as well? it works tho. thanks!

Comment: <style type="text/css" media="print">  this line did the trick into adding positioning to be included